# Display data in Tree sturcture SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, rdl

I have a dataset which pulls employee hierarchy of a company based on their levels. Query used as below:

```
;WITH DirectReports (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Level)
AS
(
SELECT [managerid] , e.EmployeeID, 
    0 AS Level
FROM Resource AS e
WHERE e.[managerid] is null and e.statecode=0
UNION ALL

SELECT e.[mtctb_resourcemanageridname], e.EmployeeID, Level +  1
FROM Resource AS e
INNER JOIN Resource AS d
    ON e.[managerid] = d.EmployeeID
    join DirectReports AS dr on  e.[managerid] = dr.EmployeeID
    where e.statecode=0
)

SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID,  Level
FROM DirectReports 
WHERE EmployeeID is not null
```

Need to display in report as below.[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - paste the code directly into your question.

Comment: Okay Siyual will update it soon.

Comment: The visualization you are after is not supported in SSRS. However you can show hierarchical data using a tablix with the right formats to differentiate every level. Let me know if that sounds like something that could help.

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27848804/Tree-TreeView-and-Framing-in-an-SSRS-2008-R2-report.html

Comment: @zuleta Thanks for the reponse. I have already done it with tablix but trying to achieve the design from top to bottom rather than left to right.

Comment: @Hiten Thank for sharing the link might be helpful for someone :)